# I am getting an error message on the browser while trying to output this

Tags: php

this is what the error says Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '?> ', expecting function (T_FUNCTION)

```
class DB {
    protected $db_name = 'nklopP';
        protected $db_user = 'root';
        protected $db_pass = 'nyiyfyfy2013';
        protected $db_host = 'localhost';

        //open a connection to the database. Make sure this is called
        //on every page that needs to use the database.
        public function connect() {
             $connection = mysql_connect($this->db_host, $this->db_user, $this->db_pass);
            mysql_select_db($this->db_name);

            return true;
        }
```

Comment: Unless I'm missing it, you didn't include the relevant code.

Comment: I have done some editing please look at it now

Comment: the code that has `?>` in it... That's the problem

Comment: Why use a class with `mysql_*` functions? tsk tsk

Comment: fred I dont understand your comment

Comment: @ochieng: The `mysql_*` family of functions are deprecated. You are **strongly** encouraged to migrate to PDO or the `mysqli_*` family of functions.

Comment: @ochieng `mysql` is deprecated. You should be using `mysqli` or `PDO`. I prefer `PDO`.

Comment: @ochieng Don't forget to click the accept answer for the most helpful answer if your problem is solved (I see you're newer to SO).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you'e going for the OOP style, you should consider doing your DB class like so:

```
<?php
class DB
{
    protected $db_name = 'nklopP';
    protected $db_user = 'root';
    protected $db_pass = 'nyiyfyfy2013';
    protected $db_host = 'localhost';

    protected $link;

    //open a connection to the database. Make sure this is called
    //on every page that needs to use the database.
    public function connect() 
    {
        $this->link = new mysqli($this->db_host, $this->db_user, $this->db_pass, $this->db_name);

        return true;
    }   
} // This is most likely where you went wrong, because you forgot to end the class.     

?>
```

Comment: Heh, we both assumed the same thing. I tried to get him to show all of the code.

Comment: Yeah, it would appear that the conclusion we came to is right, seeing as he didn't end the class so it's taking into account that the ?> is still within the class.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your full code (which you won't show for some reason), looks something like this:

```
<?php

class DB {
    protected $db_name = 'nklopP';
        protected $db_user = 'root';
        protected $db_pass = 'nyiyfyfy2013';
        protected $db_host = 'localhost';

        //open a connection to the database. Make sure this is called
        //on every page that needs to use the database.
        public function connect() {
             $connection = mysql_connect($this->db_host, $this->db_user, $this->db_pass);
            mysql_select_db($this->db_name);

            return true;
        } 
?>
```

The solution would be something like this:

```
<?php
class DB {
    protected $db_name = 'nklopP';
        protected $db_user = 'root';
        protected $db_pass = 'nyiyfyfy2013';
        protected $db_host = 'localhost';

        //open a connection to the database. Make sure this is called
        //on every page that needs to use the database.
        public function connect() {
             $connection = mysql_connect($this->db_host, $this->db_user, $this->db_pass);
            mysql_select_db($this->db_name);

            return true;
        }
    } // <---- fix your syntax errors!
?>
```

But there's no telling if you don't show all of the relevant code.

Comment: lol I guess am little tired thanks m59 where do i click to accept answer

Comment: @ochieng there's a checkmark under the score to the left of the answers.

Comment: Thanks very helpful.one last question whats the difference between mysql and mysqli

Comment: MySQL is now decapitated along with all of its classes and MySQLi has the updated library full of new classes with less security risks

Comment: @ochieng ^ yeah that. `PDO` has some really nice things that I prefer over `mysqli`, like named parameters.

Comment: thanks alot ill try pdo I assume all this is available in xampp

Comment: so the mysqli expects expects exactly 2 parameters how do I handle that when establishing a connection e.g. here mysqli_select_db("nklopP") or die(mysql_error());

Comment: @ochieng that's beyond the scope of this post (not appropriate for the comments here). There are posts on SO about that already, just search.

Comment: ok thanks ill look for them